# Items from data template

Tags: windows-runtime, datatemplate

I am trying to access a webview item that's inside a flipview. This webview was declared inside a datatemplate of the flipview. Does anyone know how I can access the webview so that I can do things with it?

Answer (score 0):

Move the contents of the DataTemplate into a UserControl and use that as your ItemTemplate. Then you can easily do whatever you want in that UserControl.

Comment: If I done that then how would I be able to get the objects, wouldn't I have the same problem

Comment: It depends where you want to access that WebView from. If you want to do it from the page then no, you still can't, but now you can access it easily from the UserControl level. Another problem is though that a WebView won't work well inside of a FlipView unless you switch it to WebViewBrush most of the time.

Comment: Yea ive made a program that uses the WebViewBrush, but the webview was outside of the flipview. Now trying to make it so the webview is inside is proving much more difficult

Comment: Well, let me know if there is any other way I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up the best way was binding the web view item to a different property of the item, and then displaying what was in that property (NodeValue)